# Как обнулить локальную переменную статического класса в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

```
import time
class Abc:
    list=[] #вот это нужно обнулять по условию
    def abc(self):
        self.list.append(1) #работает
        print(self.list,end=' ') #работает
        if sorted(self.list)==sorted(some_other_list):
            list =[] # del, None; self.list, Abc().list - ничего не срабатывает
            print('list = some_other_list') # срабатывает по условию
        else:
            pass
some_other_list=[1,1,1,1,1,1]
while 1==1:
    Abc().abc()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    #Abc().list=[] #даже это не работает!
```

Comment: `Abc.list=[]` ;)

Comment: как тут плюса влепить? :D

Comment: И не называйте переменные ключевыми словами питона, потом сюрприз будет. `list` - это плохое название для переменной.

Comment: @CrazyElf, не могу себе представить как может помешать __атрибут класса__ с названием list/dict/etc. ;) Хотя с общим правилом я конечно согласен)

Comment: да я этот код накатал чисто под вопрос, это не часть проекта. вопрос - почему с переменной list работает конструкция self.list.append(1), но не работает self.list=[]?

Comment: @ПавелДровенников Я накатал вам ниже в ответе длинное объяснение, если что-то всё-равно непонятно - спросите там в комментарии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё же объясню, почему всё так странно. На каждой итерации цикла вы **создаёте новый объект** и вызываете его функцию:

```
Abc().abc()
```

Даже если вы в этой функции присвоите полю `self.list` пустой список - на следующей итерации цикла этот факт не будет иметь никакого значения, потому что там опять создастся новый объект.

Хорошо, но почему же новый объект "помнит" состояние `self.list` предыдущего объекта, причём не пустое состояние помнит, а пустое - не помнит? А вот поэтому:

```
class Abc:
    list=[]
```

Здесь `list` переменная класса, при этом конструктор для экземпляров класса вы не написали и ничего там в `self.list` не присвоили. Что же произойдёт, когда вы обратитесь к функции экземпляра класса?

```
    def abc(self):
        self.list.append(1)
```

Хм, что же находится в `self.list` при первом обращении к функции, если мы `self.list` никак не инициализировали? А там находится по правилам питона ссылка на переменную класса с тем же названием `list`, если таковая существует. И если вы что-то добавляете в `self.list` вы фактически добавляете в `Abc.list` - ведь это ссылка на один и тот же список. Но что будет, если мы потом что-то присвоим переменной `self.list`?

```
        self.list = []
```

А вот теперь переменная `self.list` указывает на какой-то другой список и не имеет никакой связи с `Abc.list`, но это совершенно не важно, потому что ссылку на этот класс вы не сохраняете, этот класс после выполнения функции просто выкидывается в корзину и после этого никто и никогда не узнает, что вы что-то присвоили переменной `self.list`.

Но как же сделать так, чтобы переменная класса `Abc.list` (а значит и переменная экземпляра класса `self.list` на новой итерации цикла) всё же обнулилась? Можно так:

```
Abc.list = []
```

Но можно и вот так:

```
self.list.clear()
```

Потому что мы не теряем при таком очищении связь с `Abc.list` и чистим именно этот список.

P.S. Лучше не называйте переменные ключевыми словами питона, такими как `list`. В данном случае, поскольку это поля класса, это не страшно, но на будущее лучше так никогда не делать, потому что потом будет сюрприз, когда вы присвоите переменной `list` что-нибудь, а затем захотите что-то преобразовать в список вызовом `list` как функции: `list(x)`, у вас будут непонятные ошибки при этом.